# How do I reference a class in the above directory in a C# Unity project?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a structure a bit like

```
Scripts
|_Actions
  |_Attack.cs
    ...
  SomeTrigger.cs
```

And inside `Attack.cs` I instantiate an object of type `SomeTrigger`. I'm getting a compile error that states: `The name 'SomeTrigger' does not exist in the current context`. I'm guessing it's because the file it is referenced in just doesn't know where it is. I'm hoping this can be solved with just doing the correct `using` statement, but I don't know how to use a class that is in a directory above the one I'm referencing from.

This is for a Unity project.

Comment: C# doesn't work by directory, it works by namespaces. Reference the class by the namespace it's in.

Comment: Sorry, I'm pretty new to C#. How do I know what namespace the class is in?

Comment: @justinrixx at the top of the file you'll have something like `namespace xyz { `, where `xyz` is the namespace.

Comment: @justinrixx [Here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Namespaces.html) is a Unity manual link about namespaces :) Though it's no different to standard C# (fyi).

Comment: So it doesn't matter what file something is in, I can just wrap it in a namespace and it will be accessible? Or should I just be able to reference that class since it's in the classpath (is that a thing in C#?)

Comment: Everything in C# **has** to be in a namespace. However, just having it inside there, and referencing it isn't always enough. Take a look at [C# access modifiers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxh6fsc7.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to know how to expose only what you want to. The default for classes is `internal` which means that it can't be used outside of things in that assembly.

Answer (score 0):

You could expose a public reference to the class inside `Attack.cs` and select the object containing a `SomeTrigger.cs` script using the inspector. For example:

```
public SomeTrigger myReferenceToSomeTrigger;
```

As it is public, you will see the variable in the script you put this code in in the inspector; then you can select the SomeTrigger object you want to reference from here.